# What should I do with an Id property in a View Model with HttpPost when database Id is an identity column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC program, I have a Model that looks like this:

```
public class PaycheckTypeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int CustomSortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

In my database, *Id* is an identity column.  In my controller I am creating a new record like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(PaycheckTypeViewModel paycheckType)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/api/");

        var responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<PaycheckTypeViewModel>("paycheck-type", paycheckType);

        if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error calling API to Create New Paycheck Type.");

        return View();
}
```

The paycheckType parameter contains data like this:

```
CustomSortOrder   5
Id                0
Type              New Paycheck
```

The API that handles this Post Request knows to ignore the Id because its an identity column. But my question is what is usually done in this case? I thought of using [JsonIgnore] in the Model, but I want the Id to be serialized for displaying on the screen. It doesn't break anything by having the Id in the paycheckType parameter, but I thought this might not be the best practice.

Comment: It's odd that you want to show an ID; normally it's the last thing we care about, and can often lead to trouble

Comment: @CaiusJard That's probably a good point. This is a practice project I'm working on for myself so I'm more or less making up the requirements as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, best practice for design api is to separate the actions and what they need.
for example for creating you don't need to pass id so create a dto without id.
but when you want to update you need id so create a dto that contains id.
just remember that a method responsible just for one action. SOLID principle

Comment: Woah, Dto overflow.. Creating a whole new POCO just to omit one int? One DTO for insert, another for update, another for delete? What about if one screen just updates person's name and age, other screen updates their job- separate DTO for those too?

Comment: yes one dto for update, one for create, one for delete, one for get single instance and one for list, you should separate this ones cause that you can implemented business without conflict with each other. pick up a design pattern depend on your problem then follow it.

Comment: Not very DRY then?

Comment: Not actually. when you choose a good design pattern that fit your problem then its made it easy to maintenance . well all we talk is not about a sample software that just multiply two number or just have simple crud. check the crud again (Create,Read,Update,Delete) all this method do a different action. for example if you want to do something specific in any of this action if you choose on dto for all of them and combine some of the actions. you should write very huge code to handle all of the conditions and its not good at all